# Release resources when a resource is destroyed in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

The current model I am working on involves equipments seizing resources (materials, operators) to perform taskings within the equipment. During the model run, the number of equipment (a resource as well) will be varied using a slider. Upon reduction of the resourcepool quantity, excess equipments will be destroyed. How do I release all the resources that are still seized by this equipment after it is destroyed so that the resources can continue to be utilised by the rest of the model?[image]

[image]

Comment: Just checking: you did test that they are, in fact, not released, correct?

Comment: Hi Benjamin, apologies, let me clarify. So my operators are resources, but my materials ('carriers'0 are just agents within a population pool. So in my lower flow, I simulate that a carrier is brought to the equipment and held by a delay (useCarriers) before I unblock the unload block in the upper flow. But when I destroy my equipment, I cant seem to seize an operator to shift the carrier back to the main agent to be utilised in other equipments. This led to my initial understanding that the resources are not released after destroying the equipment agent. But I'm not sure how to verify if this

Comment: Furthermore, after destroying the equipment, i tried adding new equipments back to the model run. But the carrier (yellow box) is still stucked at the equipment and the operator stays frozen (right corner of the screenshot)

Comment: I'd try to build a simple example model where you test the specific issue. Once you know what is actually happening, it is much easier to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know when you reduce the number of resource units in a resource pool they will only be destroyed once the current agents that are seizing them have released them. Thus you don't need to worry about releasing all the resources that are still seized by this equipment.

Comment: Hi Jaco-Ben, I've added a comment in response to Benjamin. Not too sure how I can proceed, or if there is something wrong with my current approach. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a design problem, but you don't really explain how your flows are linked (or when your equipment agents enter the top flow).

Your information suggests that your equipment agents go through the top flow (seizing materials and operators); your bottom flow is presumably triggered after an 'EQ run' to simulate operators doing something at the machine before unload can start/complete(?) by releasing the Hold in the top flow.

The problem is that you should never have resources (i.e., agents that are part of a resource pool) flowing through processes; agents are either flow-through-processes agents or resource agents. Changing resource pool sizes will do nothing to affect those agents if they're in a process flow because AnyLogic is only concerned about tasks those resources are doing *as resources*.

In your case, it depends what 'removing the machine' represents in real-life (given the machine is potentially processing things at the time). That will determine what 'sub-flow' you need to enact in that case to free resources, etc. This is likely to mean in your case:

- Have some trigger (e.g., event, schedule action, button action, some specific state elsewhere in your model) which means an equipment is now 'removed'.
- This then needs code to know what block that equipment is currently in (agents have a `currentBlock` function for this purpose), remove it from that block (typically using the `remove` function provided by most blocks, but this is not consistent across all blocks) and then probably send it into a 'clean-up' process flow (using an Enter block, with a Sink block at the end to delete it) to do whatever needs doing (like releasing all resources).

Some of the code needed here is slightly complex (removing agents from within a process flow is not something 'cleanly' supported by AnyLogic except in the Pedestrian library) and will involve casting (since `currentBlock` returns you the block as a generic `FlowchartBlock` supertype).

P.S. A more 'radical' design rework (but probably a better one for what you want) is to keep equipments as resource agents but redesign your top flow so that the agent represents, say, a 'request for machine processing (of something)'. Your top flow will then be seizing/releasing equipment resources along with everything else, and you can use dynamic resource pool capacity changes as you were trying to. (It is quite common in process modelling to need to 'reframe' the processes via agents which represent some abstract 'request', rather than a physical thing.)

Comment: Hi, Stuart thanks for the comments. Apologies that I didn't explain how my process works. So you are right that the bottom flow is triggered at the EQRun. But to clarify, I am creating my equipments as resources and they are seized in the main agent, and the agent flowing through these 2 flows are carriers and products, not the equipment. Nevertheless, have gained some understanding from your inputs! Thanks a lot!